# R: Find all elements from a list and write findings to another list

Tags: r, list, match

I have basically two lists A and B (list of lists) and I want to find all elements in B, which match multiple conditions from A. I did:

```
for(k in 1:length(A)) {
   matches[k] <- length(which(condition 1 &
                              condition 2 &
                              ...         &
                              condition n)
   if(matches[k] == 0) {
      matches[k] <- -9999
   } else {
     matches[k] <- which(condition 1 &
                         condition 2 &
                         ...         &
                         condition n)
     }
}
```

But that saves only one finding. I get the warning:

> "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"

I get what the problem is. which() finds multiple elements in B but cant write multiple elements to a row of a list. Any ideas on how to solve that problem?

Cheers

Comment: Do you have minimal examples of lists `A` and `B` with which possible answers could be tested - your question is very abstract currently. maybe consider making a reproducible question: [mre]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your `matches` is a vector. Try to work with a list, so you will be able to store single or multiple elements.

I would modify your code in the following way:

```
matches <- list()
for(k in 1:length(A)) {
   matches[[k]] <- length(which(condition 1 &
                              condition 2 &
                              ...         &
                              condition n)
   if(matches[[k]] == 0) {
      matches[[k]] <- -9999
   } else {
     matches[[k]] <- which(condition 1 &
                         condition 2 &
                         ...         &
                         condition n)
     }
}
```